# how to get the list of installed printers in python

Tags: python-3.x, kivy-language

**hi,**
I want to get a printer list like the picture to my python with kivy project.
I want a library or some code.
I work with a point of sale application, I want a print receipt for kitchen and customer, then and how to select a which printer goes to print kitchen or customer.
using the latest versions of python and kivy (**python 3.8.2** [https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-382/], **Kivy 1.11.1** [kivy.org], **KivyMD 0.104.0** [https://github.com/HeaTTheatR/KivyMD])
**please help me.**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zURMo.png)

Comment: Not sure if Kivy implements this, but in wxPython and almost certainly also in PyQt you can spawn a printing dialog for choosing a printer. https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.PrintDialog.html#wx-printdialog

Comment: can I work with two of kivy and wxPython in a single application?